# Svelte TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL when fetching endpoint in reactive statement

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Using SvelteKit, I have the following component:

`/index.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">
    $: {
        fetchEndpoint();
    }

    async function fetchEndpoint() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/demo');
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(`Failed load endpoint. ${e}`);
        }
    }
</script>
```

`/api/demo.ts`

```js
export async function get() {
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: 'Hi',
    };
}
```

On the first load of the page I get the following error message:

```
Failed load endpoint. TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

Why exactly is that and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the problem is that your `<script lang="ts">` runs both on the server and on the front end. When it runs on the server, it won't know what `/api/demo` is referring to. One way to fix that by running it only in the browser, like so:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/env';

async function fetchEndpoint() {
  if(browser) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/api/demo');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(`Failed load endpoint. ${e}`);
    }
  }
}
```